# Python ML Model gives wrong output in docker

Tags: python, pandas, docker, machine-learning, scikit-learn

We had been training a model in python and witnessed a very strange behavior while using Docker. When running in local system (Mac Machine) the model gives correct prediction, however when we use docker it gives the prediction which is way off from the actual. Here is how our `Dockerfile` looks like -

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt -y update &&\
    apt -y install python3 python3-pip

RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip &&\
    pip3 install -U scikit-learn

ADD ./python_requirements.txt /
RUN python3 -m pip3 install -r python_requirements.txt

ENTRYPOINT ["bash","/scripts/start_flask.sh"]
```

And here is the `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "2"

services:
  flask:
    build : .
    volumes : 
     - ../scripts:/scripts
     - ../data:/data
    ports:
     - 3000:3000
```

There are no errors in the docker apart from some warnings, which I learned can be ignored -

```
| /usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py:222: RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96, got 88
flask_1  |   return f(*args, **kwds)
flask_1  | /usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py:222: RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96, got 88
flask_1  |   return f(*args, **kwds)
flask_1  | /usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py:222: RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96, got 88
flask_1  |   return f(*args, **kwds)
flask_1  | /usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py:222: RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96, got 88
flask_1  |   return f(*args, **kwds)
flask_1  | /usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py:222: RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96, got 88
flask_1  |   return f(*args, **kwds)
flask_1  |  * Running on http://0.0.0.0:3000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

And lastly this is the script we are using to trigger the python code file

```
#! /bin/bash
cd /scripts
python3 server.py
```

Based on the comments below I did check the version of modules in docker and modules in local system and bring it in sync now both the version of modules inside container and in my local system is same as below -

```
scikit-learn==0.22.1
pandas==1.0.1
numpy==1.18.1
Flask==1.1.1
scipy==1.4.1
```

However the problem remains same. Trying since couple of days to figure out what has been wrong here. Any help and pointer will be appreciated.

BR

Comment: Are there some errors in Docker container's log? May be the app produces some errors during its runtime when it is running within the container.

Comment: @vkozyrev I have updated the question with the warning I got. There are no errors as such

Comment: do you get these warnings when you run the app outside of Docker container?

Comment: Are the modules used in your project at the same version in both your local and docker environments? I see that you install them in your dockerfile, but it may be worth checking if you experience differences in behavior.

Comment: Can you make sure the modules versions are the same ? If they are, can you try without mounting volumes, e.g by copying the needed files in the docker ? I had an issue with shared volume on docker once, some files were not detected / ignored.

Comment: @Schisme Yes i have the module versions same. Updated the question with details.